# Converting a series of synchronous methods into async in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

How do I convert this chain of synchronous method calls into async (using the async/await operators)? Given that only the last call, DoRequest(), is the one that takes time to execute, is that the only method that needs to become async? Or do all the callers in the chain, RequestSomething() and Process(), need to be made async as well?

```
[HttpGet]
void Process()
{
   var url = "http://someapi.com";
   var myObject= RequestSomething(url);
   //do something with the myObject.
}    

MyObject RequestSomething(string url)
{
   var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
   var response = DoRequest(request);
   return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(response);
}

//method that takes time to return.
HttpResponseMessage DoRequest(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    return client.SendAsync(request).Result;
}
```

Comment: `RequestSomething` does nothing.  Calling a method only to return its result adds nothing.  You can just remove it entirely.  And all `Process` does is call a method and ignore the return value.  Do you really need either of those methods?

Comment: These are in different layers of my project...I just put them together here to keep it simple.

Comment: @Servy I have updated my question to clarify what I am asking.

Comment: Make sure you stick to conventions, your method be called `ProcessAsync`, `RequestSomethingAsync` and `DoRequestAsync` respectevly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do async correctly it is "infectious", if you do it in one spot you need to do it all the way up the call chain to get any of the real benefits out of it. So whatever is calling `Process()` will need to handle the task returned from `Process` by either awaiting it or passing it up the chain like `DoRequest` does.

```
async Task Process()
{
   var url = "http://someapi.com";
   var myObject= await RequestSomething(url);
   //do something with the myObject.
}    

async Task<MyObject> RequestSomething(string url)
{
   var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
   var response = await DoRequest(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
   return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(response);
}

//method that takes time to return.
Task<HttpResponseMessage> DoRequest(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    return client.SendAsync(request);
}
```

Because you do not do any extra work after performing the request you don't need async/await in your `DoRequest` function, but the other ones will need the async/await keywords. The `.ConfigureAwait(false)` makes it so that function does not have to run the rest of its code on the UI thread, this can give you a small performance boost. I did not know if the code that is in `//do something with the myObject.` required you being on the UI thread or not, so I did not put it on that await, but if you don't need to be on the UI thread you could add it there too.

Comment: Thanks Scott.  This is starting to make sense.  Couple questions. So the await keyword would generally be used only when there are other things to do in the method after the await, right?  You would never really have an await on the last statement of the method? The other questions is, if Process() is a Web API method that gets calls by external sources, then could I just make that void, and do a RequestSomething(url).Start() instead?

Comment: Doing `.Start()` would not work, in fact the task is already started when the function returns, await acts more like a `.Result` or a `.Wait()`. Be warned using `.Result` or `.Wait()` in the same code as `await` can cause deadlocks in your system. That is why I said if you are going to do one thing async you need to make your entire call chain async. you should not call `.Wait()` half way down. Which WebAPI are you using, MVC supports returning `Task` instead of `void` and `Task<T>` instead of `T`

Comment: I am using the regular .NET Web API.

Comment: @Prabhu One thing you may want to await even if you are the last line is so if a exception is thrown it happens at the awaited point instead of hiding inside of the `Task`, if you think your caller is not going to await your task either but needs to be informed that a exception could have happened then await before you return.

Comment: I don't understand how you are using `Process()` then, if you still have questions can you update your question with a larger example showing how `Process()` might be called?

Comment: Process() is an HttpGet API method. It's a method inside my ApiController class.

Comment: Just to clarify one more thing. Say I'm not worried about exceptions. In that case, if I'm not going to do anything anyway after await in a method, say Method1(), then I don't really need to make Method1() async, I could just make the caller of Method1() async and await the result of Method1() right?

Comment: Correct, just return the `Task` instead of awaiting.

Answer (score 1):

You should make DoRequest...

```
Public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DoRequest(...
```

Then return await client.SendAsync

Similarly, DoSomething should be async Task<...>

Your calling method, Process can be async void if you want to call it as fire and forget, otherwise an async Task.

Comment: Thanks. So all of them should become async? If I just made the first method Process() as async, and awaited the result to RequestSomething, wouldn't that be enough?

Comment: Making them all async is one part. If you want Process to be awaitable, it must return a Task, otherwise return void and it can be called to trigger async but without having to return before execution on your main thread continues.

Comment: Could RequestSomething and DoRequest both return Task (and not be async), and just Process be async for this all to be asynchronous?

Comment: I almost want to give you a -1 on your answer for the comment "otherwise return void". You should NEVER return void unless you are awaiting a event handler. @Prabhu to answer your question, no you could not because you need the finished result of `DoRequest` to pass it to `DeserializeObject`

Comment: Async void is a valid construct @scottchamberlain. I've presented it here with an explanation of what it does for whoever to decide. You are correct that it is usually handled as an event handler, but it can also be used to facilitate async operation during class constructors. You are right to warn about it, but to say NEVER is a bit dramatic.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
var task = Task.Run(() => RequestSomething());
var task2 = Task.Run(() => RequestSomethingElse());

await Task.WhenAll(task, task2);
```

You can specify more than two if you like, or only one.

Comment: This is definitely wrong and not the way to go. There is no need for threadpool threads to be used to do async IO bound work.